# How to drop_duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates

I have raw data as following example. At instant t1, a variable has a value x1, this variable should be recorded at instant t2 if and only if its value is not equal to x1. There is a way to compare a value in dataframes in python with the previous value and delete it if it's the same. I tried follow function, but it doesn't work.Please help.

```
df
time                 Variable   Value
2014-07-11 19:50:20  Var1       10
2014-07-11 19:50:30  Var1       20
2014-07-11 19:50:40  Var1       20
2014-07-11 19:50:50  Var1       30
2014-07-11 19:50:60  Var1       20 
2014-07-11 19:50:70  Var2       50
2014-07-11 19:50:80  Var2       60
2014-07-11 19:50:90  Var2       70
```

Coding:

```
for y in df.time:
    for x in df.Value:
        if y == y:
            if x == x:
                df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['time', 'Variable', 'Value'], keep=False) 
            else:
                df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['time', 'Variable', 'Value'])
```

Expected output:

```
df
time                 Variable   Value
2014-07-11 19:50:20  Var1       10
2014-07-11 19:50:30  Var1       20
2014-07-11 19:50:50  Var1       30
2014-07-11 19:50:60  Var1       20 
2014-07-11 19:50:70  Var2       50
2014-07-11 19:50:80  Var2       60
2014-07-11 19:50:90  Var2       70
```

Comment: When you apply a `for` loop (or any other loop) to a dataframe, in 99% you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Variable','Value'],keep='first')
#                time Variable  Value
#2014-07-11  19:50:20     Var1     10
#2014-07-11  19:50:30     Var1     20
#2014-07-11  19:50:50     Var2     30
#2014-07-11  19:50:60     Var2     40
#2014-07-11  19:50:70     Var2     50
```

Comment: Thank you. So, why did we just take 2 subsets while we got 3?

Comment: You _do not_ want the _same variable_ with the _same value_.

Comment: Many thanks. Your answer works, but I get one issue in my data, that, at the instant t3, same var1, and value 3 is same to value 1, and I would like to keep value 3 at var1 at t3 because it's not consecutive with t1. I updated my data.

Comment: Its' a different question and requires a different answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will raise the other question.